# Chrome - How to stop converting from http to https

Tags: google-chrome

The development on chrome has become harder and harder, my react application on localhost is not working because its been hosted on http://localhost:3000. It works in Firefox

I know chrome is getting smart and preventing from loading insecure content by changing to https, but that's painful for testing in localhost

I know we can fix this by disabling some feature in chrome://flags/, can someone tell me which one is it and can I just do it for **localhost**. Chrome version **Version 79.0.3945.130**

Comment: smarter is more configurable for me ... both are less configurable day by day .... blocked/locked/disabled "for me"

Answer (score 1):

The flag to check is allow-insecure-localhost.
Check out this answer also: https://superuser.com/questions/772762/how-can-i-disable-security-checks-for-localhost

[image: allow-insecure-localhost-flag]

Edit: You're using the wrong tag as it's not a React related question, also as I'm reading again the question it's unclear if your problem is that you're being redirected from http to https, or you're having some CORS related problem or something else.